# How to get the GLTools library from SuperBible to work in Ubuntu? or an alternative?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, ubuntu, codeblocks

I recently bought the SuperBible 5th edition book.
I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I use Code::Blocks. I'm not very proficient with C++ libraries and setting up.
I wanted a book that will guide me from scratch.
I was disappointed when I saw that the book doesn't help us set up projects in Linux.

They use 2 libraries ,freeglut and GLTools.
I read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182109/Setting-up-an-OpenGL-development-environment-in-Ub) wonderful tutorial that explained the freeglut part for linux.

Now I am clueless about GLTools. I searched in debian.org for a package containing GLTools.h and there were none. 
So, I can't find the package at all.
[Here](http://www.starstonesoftware.com/OpenGL/), they do give the libraries , but it is only for Windows and Mac. 
Inclusion of a library in Ubuntu was a piece of cake(just a command in the terminal) , but I do not how I can use a Windows library for this.

Is there any other book that would help with Linux?

edit: after doing the 1st 2 steps of what HaloWebMaster said, I did a cd and went inside the gltools folder (and there was a makefile there). There I did `make all`. But this is what hapenned:

```
Package OpenEXR was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OpenEXR.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OpenEXR' found
make[1]: sdl-config: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/gltools/framework'
make[1]: freetype-config: Command not found
Package OpenEXR was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OpenEXR.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OpenEXR' found
make[1]: sdl-config: Command not found
make[1]: freetype-config: Command not found
Compiling camera.cpp
Package OpenEXR was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OpenEXR.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OpenEXR' found
make[1]: sdl-config: Command not found
make[1]: freetype-config: Command not found
Package OpenEXR was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OpenEXR.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OpenEXR' found
make[1]: sdl-config: Command not found
make[1]: freetype-config: Command not found
Compiling fs.cpp
Package OpenEXR was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OpenEXR.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OpenEXR' found
make[1]: sdl-config: Command not found
make[1]: freetype-config: Command not found
Package OpenEXR was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `OpenEXR.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'OpenEXR' found
make[1]: sdl-config: Command not found
make[1]: freetype-config: Command not found
Compiling image/image-convert.cpp
image/image-convert.cpp:7:18: fatal error: half.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Compilation failed for libgltools_a_image-convert.o: 
make[1]: *** [libgltools_a_image-convert.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/gltools/framework'
make: *** [framework] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wget http://gltools.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gltools/?view=tar
tar xzvf gltools.tar.gz
make all
```

Comment: The file that was downloaded was **index.html?view=tar**.
I ran tar xzvf index.html?view=tar.tar.gz and it extracted GLTools to the same directory.
But the 3rd command make says: "*make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.*"

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `all'

Comment: also is it possible to have the library distributed nicely in the right directories, like how it happens when I did sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev      
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev(mainly goes to usr/include)

Comment: I suggest `sudo apt-get install libopenexr-dev`

Comment: Openexr? I am not sure how I can use that. It is an image file format.
And the library you suggested by the link ,doesn't contain GLTools.h which is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way: `svn checkout http://oglsuperbible5.googlecode.c./Src/GLTools/include/om/svn/trunk/ oglsuperbible5-read-only`, then copy the files from ./Src/GLTools/include/ to somewhere in your $INCLUDE

Comment: I copied that command and put it in the terminal and it said this:
`svn: OPTIONS of http://oglsuperbible5.googlecode.c./Src/GLTools/include/om/svn/trunk': 200 OK (http://oglsuperbible5.googlecode.c.)`

I did it without that space after trunk/ and it said the same thing.
I did check at the current directory but I couldn't find "Src".